# Make input field empty even if ng model has a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
            <div ng-if="item.type === 'textAnswer'">
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Answer:</span>
                    <input type="text"
                           ng-model="item.givenAnswer">
                </label>
            </div>
```

Item.givenAnswer outputs 'testing' at the moment on page load. What would I have to do to keep the answer in item.givenAnswer but make sure the input is blank on page load?

Basically so the user can update their answer if needs be without being distracted from their previous input.

Comment: cant you put the given answer to other variable in your controller after the value has been provided to input?

Comment: I could store it in a value but I do want it to be overwritten as well. I basically just want it to be blank all the time but still have the value in the databse

Answer (score 0):

you may try $watch like below,

```
   $scope.$watch(funtion(){return item.givenAnswer;}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
         scope.someothervariable = newValue;
         // Do database update here...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-init` method to initialize input to be blank when loading page. This will change values in scope, but will keep your database intact.

You can add more logic to it, such as if the previous value is 'testing' only then set field to be empty.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/EtNfcymqt6wJBV9Bcqdw?p=preview

Further read: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit